Geopandas combine lines and concatenate
I have a geodataframe. I want to join the overlapping features and concatenate the "Text" field.
I have tried to do it with dissolve but it doesn't work
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "lines",
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "A" }, 
          "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "B" }, 
          "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 16.37797725526616, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "C" }, 
          "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 4.247235166607424, 7.041334981156978, 0.0 ], 
                                          [ 16.742636807728559, 8.986970615165774, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "D" }, 
          "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 4.247235166607424, 7.041334981156978, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
    ]
}
features = data['features']
geometries = []
properties = []
for feature in features:
    coords_3d = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    coords_2d = [[(x, y) for x, y, z in line] for line in coords_3d]
    multiline = MultiLineString(coords_2d)
    geometries.append(multiline)
    properties.append(feature['properties'])
df = pd.DataFrame(properties)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometries)

What I'm looking for is:

Combine overlapping features

How general does a solution need to be? Does your actual data only consist of MultiLineStrings? Can there be partial overlaps, i.e. could there be a geometry that is the union of A and D and would therefore overlap partially with C?

Can we assume cartesian coordinates? This looks like a GeoJSON, implying that the first two coordinates are spherical coordinates in degrees. That would add many corner cases around the poles and across the date line. Do these need to be addressed?

You need to do it in a few steps, but the following script shows an option to do this:
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "lines",
    "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "A" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 10.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "B" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 16.37797725526616, 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "C" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 4.247235166607424, 7.041334981156978, 0.0 ], 
                                        [ 16.742636807728559, 8.986970615165774, 0.0 ] ] ] } },
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Text": "D" }, 
        "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", 
                        "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 4.247235166607424, 7.041334981156978, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
    ]
}
features = data['features']
geometries = []
properties = []
for feature in features:
    coords_3d = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    coords_2d = [[(x, y) for x, y, z in line] for line in coords_3d]
    multiline = MultiLineString(coords_2d)
    geometries.append(multiline)
    properties.append(feature['properties'])
df = pd.DataFrame(properties)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometries)

print(gdf)

# Create the linestrings we want to have in the output
diss_gdf = gdf.dissolve().explode(ignore_index=True)[['geometry']]
diss_gdf["geom_id"] = diss_gdf.index

# Determine which attributes belong with which output geometries and aggregate them.
diss_intersection_gdf = diss_gdf.overlay(gdf)
concat_gdf = diss_intersection_gdf.groupby("geom_id").agg({'Text': ' '.join})

# Join the output geometries with the output attributes
result_gdf = diss_gdf.join(concat_gdf)

print(result_gdf)

Result:
                                         geometry  geom_id Text
0                          LINESTRING (0 0, 10 0)        0  A B
1                   LINESTRING (10 0, 16.37798 0)        1    B
2               LINESTRING (0 0, 4.24724 7.04133)        2  C D
3  LINESTRING (4.24724 7.04133, 16.74264 8.98697)        3    C


You can achieve the desired transformation with a few lines:
## Your code above ##

gdf_new = gpd.clip(gdf, gdf) # extract overlapping linestrings
gdf_new = gdf_new.explode(ignore_index=True) # get all linestring segment in new rows

# aggregate by linestring
gdf_new['geom_text'] = gdf_new['geometry'].astype('str') # create column to dissolve by
gdf_new = gdf_new.dissolve(by='geom_text', aggfunc={'Text' : lambda x : ", ".join(x)}).reset_index(drop=True)

print(gdf_new)

Result:
    geometry    Text
0   LINESTRING (0.00000 0.00000, 10.00000 0.00000)  A, B
1   LINESTRING (0.00000 0.00000, 4.24724 7.04133)   C, D
2   LINESTRING (10.00000 0.00000, 16.37798 0.00000) B
3   LINESTRING (4.24724 7.04133, 16.74264 8.98697)  C

